# How to move cursor small bit from left to right in a Input field

Tags: html, css

I was created a div and a input field inside of the div. In input field, I set auto focus. When page load, the cursor focusing the input field. But the cursor in touch the border, so I can't clearly see the cursor. Is any way to move the cursor from left to right. I just want, the cursor should be touch the just front of the word **Add a list**. The clear example is inside of **Stack Overflow** page and the **Title** area. Please give your advise. Thank you.

```html
<div  
    style = "white-space: normal;word-break: break-all; width: 240px; min-height: 35px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 5px; " >
    <input class = "list-name-field" id = "SAVE_LIST" autofocus="autofocus" style="width: 230px; min-height: 35px; border: 0; " type="text" name="" placeholder = "  Add a List...">
</div>
```

Comment: `padding` or `text-indent`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Rayon said, use [`padding`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) style.

```css
.list-name-field {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="white-space: normal;word-break: break-all; width: 240px; min-height: 35px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 5px;">
  <input class="list-name-field" id="SAVE_LIST" autofocus="autofocus" style="width: 230px; min-height: 35px; border: 0;" type="text" name="" placeholder="Add a List...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can set with **text-indent** OR **padding**

```css
input[type=text]{
  text-indent:15px;
}   

/*OR*/

input[type=text]{
  padding:0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div style="white-space: normal;word-break: break-all; width: 240px; min-height: 35px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 5px; ">

    <input class="list-name-field" id="SAVE_LIST" autofocus="autofocus" style="width: 230px; min-height: 35px; border: 0; " type="text" name="" placeholder="  Add a List...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Placeholder you have added a space, Simply remove that space, no need to add Css here.

Please try below.

```html
<div  style = "white-space: normal;word-break: break-all; width: 240px; min-height: 35px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 5px; " >
       
       <input class = "list-name-field" id = "SAVE_LIST" autofocus="autofocus" style="width: 230px; min-height: 35px; border: 0; " type="text" name="" placeholder = "Add a List...">
       </div>
```

Comment: There is nothing difference in the above code. Its same as mine. Please check.

Comment: Please check  `placeholder = "Add a List..."` Part.

Comment: But, I need, that placeholder word and Cursor should be move a bit from the border. Now its touching the Border. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Padding-left` in CSS in order to give it a padding to the left side than the cursor will automatically sets from the distance you defined.

```
#SAVE_LIST{
   padding-left:10px;
}
```